# Determine differential equation is periodic and find its period

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions

Assuming I have a second-order ordinary differential equation

$$[a- b\cos^2\theta] {\theta}'' +  [b\cos\theta\sin\theta] {\theta '}^2 +  g \sin\theta = 0$$

Where $b>>a>0$, and $g<0$ are constants. How can I determine if its solution is periodic and calculate its period?

I tried to calculate the expression, but it was too complicated and I couldn't get an analytical expression for the solution.

```
eqn = (a - b Cos[θ[t]]^2) θ''[t] + 
    b Cos[θ[t]] Sin[θ[t]] θ'[t]^2 + 
    g Sin[θ[t]] == 0;
sol = DSolve[{eqn, θ[0] == c1, θ'[0] == c2}, θ[t],
    t];
```

The above code caused the application to freeze. Do I have any good way to substitute the condition of $b>>a>0, g<0$ into Dsolve in order to obtain an analytical solution?

I tried a set of initial values and found that this differential equation should be periodic.

```
g = -16;
b = 10;
a = 0;
ft = 10;
initialvalue = {\[Theta][0] == Pi/2 - Pi/1000, \[Theta]'[0] == 0};
eq = (a - b Cos[\[Theta][t]]^2) (\[Theta]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] + 
    b Cos[\[Theta][t]] Sin[\[Theta][t]] Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t]^2 +
     g Sin[\[Theta][t]] == 0;
sol = NDSolve[{eq, initialvalue}, {\[Theta], \[Theta]'}, {t, 0, ft}];
theta = Plot[{\[Theta][t]*180/Pi} /. sol, {t, 0, ft}, 
   PlotRange -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "\[Theta](t)"];
```

My question is, do I have any good way to prove that this second-order differential equation is periodic? The above code can only reflect that the solution is periodic for a certain initial value, as seen from a numerical perspective.

**Update**

Perhaps we need to add some conditions to $\theta$ in order to prove it, such as $\theta\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ or $(-\pi/4,\pi/4)$. Using **Poincaré mapping** for verification may be a good choice, but I am not sure how to substitute the assumption of coefficients $b>>a>0$, and $g<0$ into the function package of mma.

Comment: Sorry, there are always problems with displaying symbols when using `SE.editor` in the second mma code.

Comment: No chance. This equation is second order, quadratic first order, nonlinear with periodic coefficients and no first integarl in sight. Looks like the output of a free associative symbol producing automaton. Consider  theta'' + sin theta =0, the pendulum equation. Has periodic ocillatory solutions, rotational solutions with positive oscillatory velocity and the 4 arctan soltution top to top in infinite time.

Comment: @RolandF thank you. Perhaps it is necessary to add some restrictions to the initial values of the equation. I am considering it. From what I understand now, some tools like Poincaré mapping may be worth trying.

Comment: why your in 1st block of code `eqn` does not look like your top math equation -- there is no even parameter `a` there ? Changing order of terms and breaking lines in random places does not help readability.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov There are some errors here, thank you for pointing them out. I have already updated them.

Comment: +1 -- thanks for correcting errors.

Comment: BTW, did you try asking at https://math.stackexchange.com or https://physics.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Yes, I also want to solve this problem through analytical methods, so I asked on math.se. I have updated my answer to this question.

Comment: [Reference on MATH](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4720049/28293)

Answer (score 2):

My current approach is to draw the vector field diagram through StreamPlot (First, make an intuitive judgment), and then use Poincare Bendixson theorem and Dulac's theorem/Criterion to judge. This is my code:

Firstly, convert it into a first-order equation. Let
$$x(t) = \theta(t), y(t) = \theta(t)'$$
so we have
$$x'(t)= y(t)$$
$$ y(t)' = - (g \sin(x(t)) + b \cos(x(t)) \sin(x(t)) y(t)^2) / (a - b \cos(x(t))^2)$$

Then, Take some initial values ​​in these areas. The complete code is as follows.

```
g = -16;
b = 10;
a = 0;
ft = 10;
eqNew = (a - b Cos[\[Theta][t]]^2) (\[Theta]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] + 
    b Cos[\[Theta][t]] Sin[\[Theta][t]] Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t]^2 +
     g Sin[\[Theta][t]] == 0;
streamPlot = 
 StreamPlot[{y, -(g Sin[x] + b Cos[x] Sin[x] y^2)/(a - 
      b Cos[x]^2)}, {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]
colors = {Red, Green, Blue};
initialConditions = {{Pi/3, -Pi/2.4}, {Pi/2.4, 0}, {-Pi/3, Pi/2}};
solutions = 
  Table[NDSolve[{eqNew, \[Theta][0] == 
      initialConditions[[i, 1]], \[Theta]'[0] == 
      initialConditions[[i, 2]]}, {\[Theta], \[Theta]'}, {t, 0, 
     20}], {i, Length[initialConditions]}];
trajectoryPlots = 
  Table[ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[{\[Theta][t], \[Theta]'[t]} /. solutions[[i]]], {t, 0, 
     20}, PlotStyle -> colors[[i]]], {i, Length[initialConditions]}];
Show[streamPlot, trajectoryPlots]
```

[image]

Finally, attempting to apply Poincare Bendixson theorem and Dulac's theorem/criterion.

**Update**

Here is a more general analysis, by multiplying the original equation by $2\theta'$ and calculating the first integral:
$$
(a-b^2\cos^2θ)θ'^2+4g\sin^2(θ/2)=C
$$

The level sets are closed curves around $(\theta,\theta')=(0,0)$. more details can see [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720049/how-to-determine-if-a-differential-equation-is-periodic-and-calculate-its-period/4720400?noredirect=1#comment10000543_4720400), the symbols used here are different in order to match the code of Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

This is just some thoughts to get you started on theoretical solution and to point out some technical tricks. I did not had time to go further yet. My version:

```
In[]:= $Version
Out[]= 13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)
```

This version for this equation

```
eqn = (a - b Cos[θ[t]]^2) θ''[t] + 
    b Cos[θ[t]] Sin[θ[t]] θ'[t]^2 + 
    g Sin[θ[t]] == 0;
```

gives the following

```
sol=DSolveValue[eqn,θ,t,Assumptions->{b>a>0,g<0}]

sol // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

So it does at least something with an inverse functions. Maybe this is enough to figure out periodicity or you might use perturbation theory for small $a$ etc. Note two details:

- You do not need to put general non-numeric constants `DSolve` - it makes them automatically
- `Assumptions` option is the thing you asked for and probably what makes it to compute

Another thing, if you assume in zero approximation $a=0$ then you can derive 1st integral, which is a useful quantity in such systems. Then maybe you can use perturbation theory again for small $a$. Here is a sketch (could be some generalizations and errors; $n=b$):

[image]

My memory of all this is quite rusty. But here is a (maybe wrong) thought. 1st integral is a conserved quantity $c$. If you plot phase-portrait momentum $p=s'$ vs. $s$ for various $c$ you can see the trajectories are bounded and periodic.

```
ContourPlot[p^2-Sqrt[1-s^2],{s,-1,1},{p,-1,1}]
```

[image]

This might translate to $θ$ and perhaps small enough perturbation term $~a$ will not break periodicity.

Another thought - potentially (not sure) you might find a general transformation of coordinates that will allow to keep term $a$ and find exact 1st integral. Also you might be able to find Hamiltonian and try to see if trajectories of phase portrait there are periodic.

Comment: Thank you, this is a new idea compared to Bendixson's theorem! Great! And I didn't expect DSolveValue to support Assumptions, it's really great.

Comment: The calculation is correct. By the way, how can we explain the periodicity of the solution for $\frac{(s')^2}{2}+C= k\sqrt{1-s^2}$? as $s=\sin\theta$, The expression $s[t]$ is also very complicated.

Comment: @lumw - I sketched some thoughts at the end.

Comment: You're right, the first integral does tell the story. The first integral can also be calculated by keeping $a$, which can be achieved by multiplying $2\theta(t)'$ in the original second order equation. But your answer provides a more general way of thinking, that is, when you can't get the first integral. Thank you!